# PHP Script Won't Run - Apache2/MySQL Servers Running, PHP Installed - Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, crm

I am trying to install a CRM on a Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) laptop to do some testing.  Installing the current versions of Apache, MySQL and PHP, and getting the CRM to run is easy.  It's when I try to go backwards and run it on a previous set of versions I run into problems.  This is what I have done:

I have installed Apache 2.2.14, MySQL 5.0.83, and PHP 5.2.8.  When I type something like `mysql --version` I get back what I would expect:  version and distribution info.  The same goes for Apache2 and PHP.  The Apache server is running and so is `mysqld`.

So when I go to my browser and look at `http://localhost/<CRM dir>/install.php` Firefox offers to open the PHP file or save it, as if it doesn't recognize the file.  What should happen is that I should get a welcome page and the installation wizard for this CRM distribution should start.  I have tried so many different things I probably screwed up something along the way.  I have restarted the servers over and over, and even recompiled the versions of MySQL and PHP with no problems.  I am hoping I am overlooking something simple because I am lost.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebuilt (recompiled) PHP and restarted the Apache2 server and it worked.  I am having a different problem, but perhaps requires a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your Apache has the proper PHP integration configured somehow.

```
LoadModule php5_module /some/path/to/modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: This is good, thanks.  I will try it as soon as I can.  Are these commands to run or lines in a configuration file?

Comment: lines in your config file (httpd.conf)

Comment: Yes, I ended up figuring this out - thanks.  The tricky part I have now is the LoadModule.  I had to take that line out to run it. My `php.ini` file is not where it should be and I can't configure Apache2/PHP correctly.