# phpinfo() does not show MySQL section

Tags: linux, mysql, php, redhat, phpinfo

This is linked to [Installing PHP with MySQL support?](https://serverfault.com/questions/191609/installing-php-with-mysql-support)

My phpinfo() does not show a MySQL section as a separate 'heading', but several .ini files are referenced and I can access it from the command line.

I did:

```
yum install php-mysql
```

which completed successfully, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about to try it after restarting web server service

Comment: ****! I ran: /usr/sbin/apachectl restart and it doesnt even run the PHP scripts anymore - its now just showing it up on the webbrowser!

Comment: It didnt report any error in apache's error_log: [Tue Oct 19 01:13:35 2010] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Tue Oct 19 01:13:35 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Oct 19 01:13:35 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Oct 19 01:13:35 2010] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Tue Oct 19 01:13:35 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: `/usr/sbin/apachectl stop` then `service httpd restart`

Comment: Well - thanks for the inputs. That and this http://serverfault.com/questions/148818/php-script-wont-run-apache2-mysql-servers-running-php-installed-ubuntu-10-0 helped out - somehow the AddHandler php5-script .php etc wasn't there